# Elliptic curve threshold cryptography in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I'd like to implement something like the [two-man rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-man_rule) using elliptic curve cryptography in javascript.

Edit: I'm essentially looking for something like Bitcoin multisig.

So I need to take combine two public keys to get a combined key that requires both private keys to produce a signature. See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25250/adding-two-public-keys.

How can I do this in node?

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/wanderer/secp256k1-node but completely in JS without the C?

Comment: Are you trying to do it in the browser or with node?

Comment: Trying to do it in node.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since elliptic curve threshold cryptosystems have the property of adding keys, why not just do that?

I've attempted this using the [`elliptic` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elliptic) for node.js, just install it with npm and then try the following

```
var EC = require('elliptic').ec;
// we use the same preset of bitcoin, but should work with the other ones too
var ec = new EC('secp256k1');

// generate two (or more) starting keypairs
var key1 = ec.genKeyPair();
var key2 = ec.genKeyPair();

// sum the public... 
var sum = key1.getPublic().add(key2.getPublic());
// ...and private keys
var psum = key1.getPrivate().add(key2.getPrivate());
```

Since public keys are `Point` objects and private keys are `BigNumber` objects, you can just call the `add()` function on both of them.
At this point, `sum` and `psum` hold your combined keys, but before using them to sign a message you'll need to create a `KeyPair` object (part of the elliptic module).

```
// generate two new random keypairs
var privateKeySum = ec.genKeyPair();
var publicKeySum = ec.genKeyPair();

// we don't care about their values
// so just import the sum of keys into them
privateKeySum._importPrivate(psum);
publicKeySum._importPublic(sum);
```

As you can see, to create a new keypair I just make new random ones and then use the `_importPrivate()` and `_importPublic()` functions to load the combined keys.

It's a bit hacky, I know, but it works.

A better solution would be to just export the KeyPair object from the module and create new ones with their constructor.

After this, just proceed as normal, like in the sample provided by the module's readme:

```
var msg = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
// Sign the message with our new combined private key
var signature = privateKeySum.sign(msg);

// Export DER encoded signature in Array
var derSign = signature.toDER();

// Verify signature using the combined public key, should return true
console.log(publicKeySum.verify(msg, derSign));
```

Using this, after the first generation, you can ask for the two (or more) public keys required to verify a message signature.
If you treat the public keys as 'passwords', you can then check a signature against any message to verify that the two public keys are the original ones.

Also, this should work with multiple keys, but it will always require **all** of them to succeed.